# Authentication failed: jenkins deployment

Tags: jenkins

I´m starting to use jenkins and I have problems with the authentication when I deploy the project. I dont know where to write the credentials.

```
Authentication failed: The host was not known and was not accepted by the configuration
```

Where could I write my credentials? I dont see that point in the configuration panel. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, I write an answer. The problem was that I needed to declare in settings.xml the login data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came on settings.xml file (in .m2), that did not have the appropriate login and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ssh keys for authentication a server section like this can be used:

```
<server>
 <id>repository-id</id>
   <username>john/username>
   <privateKey>/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
</server>
```

still you may run into trouble in jenkins. You might have to run the maven deploy once in interactive mode to accept the e.g. RSA host key.